# Unable to show values from database in membership form in oragehrm

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, symfony, orangehrm

I added two fields in membership form but unable to get values from database but its saving in database what am i doing wrong?here my code please check

I added two fields in table ohrm_membership i.e:practicetype,praticetypeother

membershipSuccess.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btnSave').click(function() {
        $('#frmMembership').submit();
    });

    $('#membership').hide();

    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        $('#membership').show();
        $('.top').hide();
        $('#membership_name').val('');
        $('#membership_praticetypeother').val('');
        $('#membership_membershipId').val('');
        $('#membershipHeading').html(lang_addMembership);
        $(".messageBalloon_success").remove();
    });

    $('#btnCancel').click(function() {
        $('#membership').hide();
        $('.top').show();
        $('#btnDelete').show();
        validator.resetForm();
    });

    $('a[href="javascript:"]').click(function(){
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var statId = row.find('input').val();
        var url = membershipInfoUrl+statId;
        $('#membershipHeading').html(lang_editMembership);
        getMembershipInfo(url);

    });

    $('#btnDelete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');


    $("#ohrmList_chkSelectAll").click(function() {
        if($(":checkbox").length == 1) {
            $('#btnDelete').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
        else {
            if($("#ohrmList_chkSelectAll").is(':checked')) {
                $('#btnDelete').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#btnDelete').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        }
    });

    $(':checkbox[name*="chkSelectRow[]"]').click(function() {
        if($(':checkbox[name*="chkSelectRow[]"]').is(':checked')) {
            $('#btnDelete').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#btnDelete').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });

    $('#btnDelete').click(function(){
        $('#frmList_ohrmListComponent').submit(function(){
            $('#deleteConfirmation').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });

    $('#frmList_ohrmListComponent').attr('name','frmList_ohrmListComponent');
    $('#dialogDeleteBtn').click(function() {
        document.frmList_ohrmListComponent.submit();
    });
    $('#dialogCancelBtn').click(function() {
        $("#deleteConfirmation").dialog("close");
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("uniqueName", function(value, element, params) {
        var temp = true;
        var currentStatus;
        var id = $('#membership_membershipId').val();
        var memCount = membershipList.length;
        for (var j=0; j < memCount; j++) {
            if(id == membershipList[j].id){
                currentStatus = j;
            }
        }
        var i;
        var name = $.trim($('#membership_name').val()).toLowerCase();
        var pratice = $.trim($('#membership_practice').val()).toLowerCase();
        var praticetypeother =$.trim($('#membership_praticetypeother').val()).toLowerCase();

        for (i=0; i < memCount; i++) {

            arrayName = membershipList[i].name.toLowerCase();
            if (name == arrayName) {
                temp = false
                break;
            }

            arrayPratice = membershipList[i].pratice.toLowerCase();
            if (pratice == arrayPratice) {
                temp = false
                break;
            }
            arrayPraticetypeother = membershipList[i].praticetypeother.toLowerCase();
            if (praticetypeother == arrayPraticetypeother) {
                temp = false
                break;
            }


        }




        if(currentStatus != null){
            if(name == membershipList[currentStatus].name.toLowerCase()){
                temp = true;
            }
            if(pratice == membershipList[currentStatus].pratice.toLowerCase()){
                temp = true;
            }
        }

        return temp;
    });

    var validator = $("#frmMembership").validate({

        rules: {
            'membership[name]' : {
                required:true,
                maxlength: 50,
                uniqueName: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'membership[name]' : {
                required: lang_NameRequired,
                maxlength: lang_exceed50Charactors,
                uniqueName: lang_uniqueName
            }

        }

    });
});

function getMembershipInfo(url){

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $('#membership_membershipId').val(data.id);
        $('#membership_name').val(data.name);
        $('#membership_practice').val(data.practice);
        $('#membership_praticetypeother').val(data.praticetypeother);
         $('#membership').show();
        $(".messageBalloon_success").remove();
        $('.top').hide();
    });
}
```

MembershipForm .php
    class MembershipForm extends BaseForm {

```
    private $membershipService;

    public function getMembershipService() {
        if (is_null($this->membershipService)) {
            $this->membershipService = new MembershipService();
            $this->membershipService->setMembershipDao(new MembershipDao());
        }
        return $this->membershipService;
    }

    public function configure() {


        $this->setWidgets(array(
            'membershipId' => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
            'name' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
            'praticetypeother' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
            'practice' =>  new sfWidgetFormSelect(array(
        "choices" => array('Fin' => 'Fin','HRM' => 'HRM','SCM'=>'SCM','CRM'=>'CRM','Others'=>'Others') 
        )),
        ));

        $this->setValidators(array(
            'membershipId' => new sfValidatorNumber(array('required' => false)),
            'name' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true, 'max_length' => 50)),
            'practice' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true, 'max_length' => 100)),
            'praticetypeother' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false, 'max_length' => 100)),

        ));
         $membershipList = $this->getMembershipService()->getMembershipList();

        foreach ($membershipList as $membership) {
            $list[] = array('id' => $membership->getId(), 
                             'name' => $membership->getName(),
                             'practice'=>$membership->getPracticetype(),
                             'praticetypeother'=>$membership->getPraticetypeother());
        }



        $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('membership[%s]');


    }

    public function save() {

        $membershipId = $this->getValue('membershipId');
        if (!empty($membershipId)) {
            $membership = $this->getMembershipService()->getMembershipById($membershipId);
        } else {
            $membership = new Membership();
        }
        $membership->setName($this->getValue('name'));
        $membership->setPracticetype($this->getValue('practice'));
        $membership->setPraticetypeother($this->getValue('praticetypeother'));

        $membership->save();
    }

    public function getMembershipListAsJson() {


        $list = array();
        $membershipList = $this->getMembershipService()->getMembershipList();

        foreach ($membershipList as $membership) {
            $list[] = array('id' => $membership->getId(), 
                             'name' => $membership->getName(),
                             'practice'=>$membership->getPracticetype(),
                             'praticetypeother'=>$membership->getPraticetypeother());
        }

        return json_encode($list); 
    }


}
```